# port pipes all requests to a php file

Tags: php, apache, port, pipe

how can I setup httpd.conf so that I can pipe all requests to that port go to a php file?

I am trying to make a socket connection from action script to localhost in flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VirtualHosts...

To have a virtual host work specifically for that port, add the port number to the first line of the virtual host configuration. The first line should look something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost ip_address_of_your_server:12331>
```

You must also add

```
Listen 12331
```

to the httpd.conf

Now your server is listening to port 12331. In the VirtualHost configuration you can set the DirectoryIndex to route all default requests to a PHP file

```
<VirtualHost ip_address_of_your_server:12331>
DirectoryIndex myPhp.php
</VirtualHost>
```

In addition you could also use mod_rewrite and .htaccess files to route specific requests to the same PHP file as well.

I referred to: http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.2-Manual/ref-guide/s1-apache-virtualhosts.html

Comment: "In addition you could also use mod_rewrite and .htaccess files to route specific requests to the same PHP file as well." Just a pointer its a common misconception that you need to do this sort of thing within a .htaccess file. Anything that can be done in a .htaccess file can be done in a virtualhost section. if you then turn off overrides eg. AllowOverides None (in virtual host or main section) then the server doesnt need to look for a .htaccess file, which in returns reduces the load.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your virtual host with your single php script as the only file in the web root, then add a 404 error handler to point to that file.

e.g.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /script.php
```

C.

Comment: This is clever, but totally throws the RFC in the roundfile. Pedantic sysadmins and SEO pros everywhere groan.